# how to obtain posterior predictives in rjags?

Tags: r, jags, rjags, goodness-of-fit, r2jags

I would like to create a plot like this, where y is the observed data and yrep is the predictions using rjags:

[image]

I looked at the code from the example here: [JAGS and R: Obtain posterior predictive distribution for specific x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361931/jags-and-r-obtain-posterior-predictive-distribution-for-specific-x)

but I don't understand why they use:

```
for(i in 1:3){
    yP[i] ~ dt(intercept+slope*xP[i],tau,nu)
}
```

specifically, why are they using

```
dt()
```

If my overall model looks like this:

```
jagsscript <- cat("
model {

###priors####

    alpha.m ~ dunif(1,100);
    beta.m ~ dunif(0,1);

    
    s.a.sd ~ dunif(0,3);
    s.b.sd ~ dunif(0,3);

    
    sigmaObs ~ dunif(0,2);

    for(i in 1:Ndata){
    
      pRR[i] <- alpha[i] * SS[i] * exp(-1*beta[i]*SS[i]); 
      lRR[i] ~ dnorm(log(pRR[i]) - (pow(sigmaObs,2)/2),pow(sigmaObs,-2));       
      
      lalpha[i] <- log(alpha.m) + s.a[stream[i]];
      lbeta[i] <- log(beta.m) + s.b[stream[i]];
      
      
      alpha[i] <- exp(lalpha[i]); 
      beta[i] <- exp(lbeta[i]);
      
    }

    for(SS in 1:Nstream){
      s.a[SS] ~ dnorm(0,pow(s.a.sd,-2));
      s.b[SS] ~ dnorm(0,pow(s.b.sd,-2));
    }


  }
}  
", 
file = here(modelScript.name))
```

My thought is that I would do something like this:

```
  for(i in 1:Nstream){
    yP[i] ~ dt(alpha[i] * SS[i] * exp(-1*beta[i]*SS[i]),XXX,YYY)
  }
```

But I don't understand what would go in place of XXX and YYY like they had in the linked example, or if using dt() is even appropriate.

Comment: Did you go back to the original source of that code, the one referenced in the earlier question? https://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2015/10/posterior-predicted-distribution-for.html

Comment: Yes, and I still dont understand why they are using dt(), hence the reason I am posting here

Comment: In JAGS, `dt` is the function to calculate the probability density for the Student t distribution. A good resource on JAGS is the user manual, the most recent version of which you can download here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/Manuals/4.x/ For `dt`, see pages 34 and 48 of the manual, the latter of which describes the arguments - the things that would go in the place of XXX and YYY in your question.